# Mariadb: Foreign key is always NULL

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-python

Il trying to create foreign key in my table s2.
I saw that the column id_s1 in my table s2 is always NULL.
My code is below:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE s1 (
    id binary(8) primary key, Cp VARCHAR(10), 
    name varchar(10),  
    capital VARCHAR(10)); »)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO s1 (id, Cp, name, capital)
     VALUES (uuid(),%s, %s, %s )", (x1, x2, x3))
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE s2 (
    id binary(8) primary key, 
    Dpt VARCHAR(10), 
    Nation VARCHAR(10), 
    id_s1 binary(8), 
    FOREIGN KEY(id_s1) REFERENCES s1(id)); »)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO s2 (id, Dpt, nation)
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (x1, x2, x3))
cnx.commit()
```

Comment: maybe because you need to commit the DDL first.

Comment: Can you tell me What do you mean please? Thank you

Comment: yes so execute your DDL scripts and commit and then execute another cursor statement for inserts

Comment: Yes i did this.. but it is always NULL

Comment: Are the two `x1` values different?  Seems like they need to be.  Where is the code to pull out the `uuid()`?  That value cannot be squeezed into 8 bytes without loss.  Consider switching to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  (And read about that.)